# IsEnable binding not works

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Im trying to change enable status of all view from toolbar item command. I can change some strings with it but not the enable status.

This is my View which i wanted to disable or enable it.

```
 <views:UserProfileView IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}" BindingContext="{Binding ProfileContainer.UserDataModel}" x:Name="UserProfileTab"></views:UserProfileView>
```

UserProfileView's IsEnable property never changes after ctor or ToolbarEditAndSave command.

And this is part of my model :

```
    ...(in ctor)
       ToolBarText = "Edit";
       Editable = false;
       ToolbarCommand = new Command(ToolbarEditAndSave);
    ...
private void ToolbarEditAndSave()
        {
            if (ToolBarText == "Edit")
            {
                Editable = true;
                ToolBarText = "Save";
            }
            else if (ToolBarText == "Save")
            {
                //Save

                ToolBarText = "Edit";
                Editable = false;
            }
        }

        string toolBarText;
        public string ToolBarText
        {
            get { return toolBarText; }
            set
            {
                if (toolBarText != value)
                {
                    toolBarText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        bool editable;
        public bool Editable
        {
            get { return editable; }
            set
            {
                if (editable != value)
                {
                    editable = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Why this code not work?

Comment: Try this : `<views:UserProfileView BindingContext="{Binding ProfileContainer.UserDataModel}" x:Name="UserProfileTab" IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}"></views:UserProfileView>`. Just change the order in which properties are set.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple demo to simulate your code, the main code is as follows:

UserDataModel.cs

```
 public class UserDataModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public UserDataModel()
    {
        ToolBarText = "Edit";
        Editable = true;

        EditCommand = new Command(
            execute: () =>
            {
                Editable = true;
                ToolBarText = "Edit";
                RefreshCanExecutes();
            },
            canExecute: () =>
            {
                return true;
            });

        SaveCommand = new Command(
            execute: () =>
            {
                Editable = false;
                ToolBarText = "Save";
                RefreshCanExecutes();
            },
            canExecute: () =>
            {
                return true;
            });
    }

    void RefreshCanExecutes()
    {
        (EditCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();
        (SaveCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();
    }


    public ICommand EditCommand { private set; get; }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { private set; get; }


    private void ToolbarEditAndSave()
    {
        if (ToolBarText.Equals("Edit"))
        {
            Editable = true;
            ToolBarText = "Save";
        }
        else if (ToolBarText.Equals("Save"))
        {
            //Save
            Editable = false;
            ToolBarText = "Edit";
        }
    }


    string toolBarText;
    public string ToolBarText
    {
        private set { SetProperty(ref toolBarText, value); }
        get { return toolBarText; }
    }

    bool editable;
    public bool Editable
    {
        private set { SetProperty(ref editable, value); }
        get { return editable; }
    }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext >
    <switchdemo:UserDataModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackLayout  Margin="2,2,2,2" BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="50">
        <Label Text="{Binding ToolBarText }" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Entry  IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}"   Placeholder="Name" PlaceholderColor="Olive"/>

    <Button Text="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" />
    <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The effect is as follows:

[image]

Note:

1. The way you compared the value of string is not correct. It should look like this

   `if (ToolBarText.Equals("Edit"))`   not  `if (ToolBarText == "Edit")`
2. Command should need some event  to trigger.

Comment: thanks for answer. But this is not a big diffrence between my code. I just found my real problem is im binding IsEnable  bool and bindingContext to same view. If i remove binding context it works fine. But I need to use them together and separitly. Because this Binding vals on different layers on my page.

Comment: Could you please post more details about your question?

Comment: Yeah, of course. its basicly im trying to bind 2 different data to same view object. one for BindingContext one for IsEnable. But BindingContext block IsEnable binding. In your example can you try to use binding context and binding to IsEnable same time?

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh in the comments is right. Unfortunately, it has to do with the order of the properties. What happens is this: the `IsEnabled` is applied, but then the `Command` is assigned.

The `Command` has a `CanExecute` property that will also influence if a control is enabled or not. If no logic is assigned to the `CanExecute`, it will always return true.

In this case, if you set `IsEnabled="false"` but then assign the command, it will suddenly set `IsEnabled` to true again. There is [an issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2758) on the Xamarin.Forms repository for this, but fixing it will have a big impact.

For now, you could either look into the order, or implement logic for the command to determine the right value for `CanExecute`

Comment: thanks for answer. But this is not a big diffrence between my code. I just found my real problem is im binding IsEnable bool and bindingContext to same view. If i remove binding context it works fine. But I need to use them together and separitly. Because this Binding vals on different layers on my page

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. I added Editable propery to my sub models too then set them when change necessary.

```
 private void ToolbarEditAndSave()
    {
        if (ToolBarText.Equals("Edit"))
        {
            Editable = true;
            ToolBarText = "Save";
        }
        else if (ToolBarText.Equals("Save"))
        {
            //Save

            ToolBarText = "Edit";
            Editable = false;
        }

        ProfileContainer.UserDataModel.Editable = Editable;
        if (ProfileContainer.Dog1ProfileViewModel != null)
            ProfileContainer.Dog1ProfileViewModel.Editable = Editable;
        if (ProfileContainer.Dog2ProfileViewModel != null)
            ProfileContainer.Dog2ProfileViewModel.Editable = Editable;
    }
```

I think binding context override another bindings, if there is way to use Binding Context with another binding please share.